# Entity Framework Function Import Swallowing SqlException

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-4

I have noticed a problem stored procedure that is executed via an EF function import.

The sproc causes a foreign key constraint error, but I never see this exception in my app. I've checked to make sure that none of my code is handling the exception.

I do get an exception with Linq to SQL.

Has this happened to anyone? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that.  You could try turning on VS exception handling to break on any exception (handled or unhandled) and see what code is handling the exception.  That doesn't solve the problem, but it gives you a place to start.

Also, verify that the proc itself isn't where the error-swallowing is happening.  I worked on something today where the proc had an error but due to poor error-handling code (mine) didn't re-throw the exception it caught.